# View text and alert box after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to see text "Example" and alert success after 3 seconds in same time. Now only text work but alert box stands all time. What I need to change in this code?

HTML

```
<div class="alert alert-success">  
<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 

<p id="free" class="hid">

Example

</p>  

</div>
```

CSS

```
p.hid {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('free');

  removeClass(el, 'hid');
}, 3000);

function removeClass(el, className) {
  if (el.classList) {
    el.classList.remove(className);
  } else {
    el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' +
        className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
  }
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpJJXp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJzzGz

I change `p.hid` to `.hid`, add id `#alert` to div `.alert`, and change `var el = document.getElementById('free');` to `var el = document.getElementById('alert');`

Now code look like this:

**html**

```
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-success hid">  
  <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 
  <p id="free">Example</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.hid {
  display: none;
}
```

**javascript**

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('alert');

  removeClass(el, 'hid');
}, 3000);

    function removeClass(el, className) {
      if (el.classList) {
        el.classList.remove(className);
      } else {
        el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' +
            className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
      }
    }
```